# Cypher: which assignment operator

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would appreciate some Cypher-specific **theory** for why there are, effectively, two different assignment operators in the language. I can get things to work, but feel like something is missing...

Let's use Neo4j's movie database with the following query:

```
match (kr:Person {name:"Keanu Reeves"}), (hw:Person{name:"Hugo Weaving"}), p=shortestPath((kr)-[*]-(hw)) return p
```

Sure, the query works, but here's the point of my question: 'kr', 'hw' and 'p' are all variables, right? But why is it that the former two are assigned with a colon, but the latter takes an equal sign?

Thanks.

Comment: If you received satisfactory answers, please mark one of them accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that the `:` used for nodes and relationships really doesn't have anything to do with variable assignment at all, it's instead associated with node labels and relationship types.

A node label and a relationship type always start with a `:`, even if there isn't a variable present at all. This helps differentiate a node label or relationship type from a variable (a variable will never begin with a `:`), and the `:` naturally acts as a divider between the label/type and the variable when both are present. It's also possible to have a variable on a node or label, but omit the type...in that case no `:` will be present, which again reinforces that it doesn't have anything to do with assignment.

In the context of a map `{}` (such as a properties map, including when it's inlined within a match on a node or relationship), then the `:` is used for map key/value pairs, and is common syntax, used in JSON representation.

Actual assignment (such as in SET clauses, and in your example of setting the path variable to a pattern within a match) uses `=`.

Comment: Got it. That complements Gabor's answer nicely. So, in contrast to the equal sign, the colon is simply part of JSON-esque ASCII art, since there can be either a :TYPE without a variable or a dangling variable as in MATCH (n) RETURN n. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a deep theoretical reason for it. The original idea of Cypher was to provide an ASCII art-style language, where the `MATCH` part of the query which resembles a graph pattern that you'd draw on a whiteboard.

In many ways, a graph instance is quite similar to a [UML Object Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram) (and other common representations), where you would use `name : type` to denote an object's variable name and type (class) or just use `: type` for anonymous instances.

Now paths do not really fit into that picture. On a whiteboard, I'd just put the relevant part in a dashed/circled area write `p` or `p=` next to it. Definitely not `p:`.

Note that it is possible to rephrase your query to a more compact form:

```
match p=shortestPath((kr:Person {name:"Keanu Reeves"})-[*]-(hw:Person {name:"Hugo Weaving"}))
return p
```

Here, using colons everywhere would look out of place, think: `p:shortestPath((kr:Person {name:"Keanu Reeves"})`

**Remark 1.** If you try to use a variable to capture relationships of a variable length pattern, you will get a warning:

> Warning. This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
>
> Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated. (org.neo4j.graphdb.impl.notification.NotificationDetail$Factory$2@1eb6644d)

```
MATCH (a)-[rs:REL*]->(b)
                 ^
```

So you would better use a path and the [`relationships`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-relationships) function to get the same result:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[:REL*]->(b)
RETURN relationships(p)
```

**Remark 2.** I come from an OO background and have been writing Cypher for a few years, so it might just be me getting used the syntax -- it might be odd for newcomers, especially from different fields.

**Remark 3.** The openCypher project now provides a grammar specification 
, which gives you an insight of how a [`MATCH` clause](https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/M07/railroad/Pattern.html) is parsed.

Comment: Very interesting; thank you very much, indeed. I do see your point. So, there's no "theory", just an empirical rule that we use a colon before a node and an equal sign before a path. Is that how you would summarize this?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Also note that both characters are used for value comparisons: `MATCH (kr:Person {name: "Keanu Reeves"}) RETURN kr` is compiled to the exact same query plan as `MATCH (kr:Person) WHERE kr.name = "Keanu Reeves" RETURN kr`.